# How to use Maki svg icons with Snap.svg?

Tags: svg, icons, snap.svg

I'm experimenting with Snap in order to use svg and need to be able to use the Maki icons defined in https://github.com/mapbox/maki.

My plan is to load the svg's I need, and then instantiate them for particular icons on a piece of Snap paper. But in order for this to work, I need to place the icon at a particular place on the paper, but I can't get translation to work. Neither one of the translation techniques below works; the code works as is, but always places the icon at the top left.

What am I missing? There's not enough documentation on Snap, and I don't know if the problem is with the way the Maki icon svg is defined, or my use of Snap.

```
    var icon = Snap.load("maki/bicycle-24.svg", function(f) {

        var g = f.select("g").clone();
        // var g = f.select("#layer1").clone(); // also works

        // g.transform("t120,120");

        // var t = new Snap.Matrix();
        // t.translate(120,120);
        // g.transform(t);
        paper.append(g);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The cloning needs to happen after the append, as when loading an svg in Snap its just a fragment.

So you will need to do something like...

```
paper.append(f);
var element = paper.select('#someId').clone();
element.transform( myTransform );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!  That did the trick!  And since Snap is so poorly documented, I'm going to insert the code here that allows a general solution.

```
        // Base set from which markers are constructed
    var iconSet = paper.group();
    iconSet.attr({ class: 'hide' });

        // Instantiations of icons
    var markers = paper.g();

        // Now, create SVG shape
    var icon = Snap.load("maki/bicycle-24.svg", function(icon) {
            // Add it to the icon set
        iconSet.append(icon);

            // Instantiate it and remove from main view
        var element = paper.select('#svg4460');                 // Copies it!
        // var element = paper.select('#base');                // Selects something but doesn't work
        // var element = paper.select('#layer1');              // Selects something but doesn't work
        // var element = paper.select('#bicycle-24');          // Silent fail
        element = element.clone();
        element.remove();

            // Clone this icon and move it
        var t = new Snap.Matrix();
        t.translate(10,120);
        element.transform(t);

            // Insert into main document view (markers)
        markers.add(element);
    });
```